# Why is my angular service 'then' method returning a resolved promise intead of the value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I am not understanding why "result" is a resolved promise instead of the actual value here:

```
searchService.getLink(vm.queryObject).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

The code for `getLink()` is as follows:

```
function getLink(query) {
    return $resource(uriService.searchLink).save(query).$promise;
}
```

I'm doing something very similar elsewhere and I get the value in the `then()` callback instead. What am I missing?

**Update** I was mistaken, "result" is a Resource object that has a promise on it. But the question remains, why isn't the value of the promise being passed to the callback?

Comment: i think the actual behavior of .then is to return promise while is .success is returning the data

Comment: what do you think `$promise` is? Try `result.data`

Comment: @charlietfl I think he understands that `$promise` is a promise. What doesn't make sense is why when he returns that promise, calls `then` on it, and gets the `result` value given as an argument, *that* object is also a promise. Normally promises aren't meant to resolve until they have a non-promise object. I don't know Angular 1 well, but this is confusing me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out it was because of how I was returning data from the server. I just wanted to return an id from the server so I was trying this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("search/link")]
public int Link(SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
{
    return _searchService.Save(searchCriteria);
}
```

But $resource must require an object to be returned from the server, so I modified my return type to be an object and then the value started appearing as a property on that object.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("search/link")]
public GenericModel<int> Link(SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
{
    return new GenericModel<int> { Data = _searchService.Save(searchCriteria) };
}
```

`GenericModel<T>` is just a class I made to wrap values for this purpose.

```
public class GenericModel<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```